# Spacing in my Output slightly off in C

Tags: c, printf

```
700   =   17 + 683
702   =   11 + 691
704   =   3 + 701
706   =   5 + 701
```

As you can see...the 3 and 5 is in the wrong place it should be:

```
700   =   17 + 683
702   =   11 + 691
704   =    3 + 701
706   =    5 + 701
```

My code for this:

```
fprintf(fpout, "%d   =   %d + %d\n", lower, primeNum1, primeNum2);
```

I'm assuming I need to use some special technique to resolve this issue. Could someone please help here.

Comment: Try "%3d = %3d + %3d\n"

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a minimum field width by putting a number between the `%` and the `d`.  When the converted value is shorter than the minimum field width, the field will be padded on the left with spaces.

```
fprintf(fpout, "%3d   =   %2d + %3d\n", lower, primeNum1, primeNum2);
```

Of course, you may need to give some thought to what the appropriate minimum field widths are based on your expected values for `lower`, `primeNum1`, and `primeNum2`.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the field widths:

```
printf(fpout, "%3d = %3d + %3d\n", lower, primeNum1, primeNum2);
```